# php code (getting json results)

Tags: php, html, json

i am completely new to php from python. in python, i am fairly familiar with getting json results from webpages. however whatever i seem to do in php is not working. the code i am using is.

```
 <?php 
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=hello&safe=off";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
echo $data; 
?>`
```

yet this does absolutely nothing. is there anything wrong with what i am doing? also i ran it through ideone.com and got these errors.

```
`PHP Warning:    file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/VQMKwy/prog.php on line 3

PHP Warning:file_get_contents(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=hello&safe=off): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/VQMKwy/prog.php on line 3`
```

Comment: Server/DNS configuration problem perhaps?

Comment: make sure `allow_url_fopen = 1` in `php.ini`

Comment: and also echo $data; is not right. you need to do print_r($data). print_r is for array.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you'll solve the problem posted above (which seems related to your server configuration, as `file_get_contents` works fine for me) you'll encounter another error.

`json_decode` will return an object of class stdClass. You can't just `echo` that out.
The fastest way to echo an array is to use

```
var_dump($data);
```

apart from that, the code runs fine on my local machine. I've just replaced `echo` with `var_dump`

---

The [hint posted by Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160459/php-code-getting-json-results/16160526#comment23094135_16160459) should solve the problem but if it doesn't and if you're running on Apache try to run this command:

```
sudo rc.d stop httpd; sudo rc.d start httpd
```

this will force Apache to stop and start thus updating `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: the var_dump($data); worked for this. and the server problems were from running it on a code testing site. i ran it on my actual server and everything worked fine.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark as correct if the post helped you. Thanks